# Different JS files for different CI Pages

Tags: php, codeigniter

My codeigniter application has a register page and a login page that both use javascript as there way of submitting their perspective forms. They share a common layout that consists of a header and a footer. The only difference is the javascript code for each of them are different. I'm wanting to find out what methods are available to me that I can have the register page use the register.js and the login page use the login.js file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a helper, which will add the js files dynamically to the header. You can find a more detailed description [here](http://jamshidhashimi.com/2013/04/12/dynamically-add-javascript-and-css-files-in-codeigniter-header-page/).

So basically it appends the js files and css files to a config item. There will be another helper function to write the header section. Call it in your header file.